# Using "make" command not working

Tags: command-line, python, sagemath

I'm working on installing sage, and I now just need to run the "make" command in the command line, but when I do I get the following:

/usr/bin/env: 'python': No such file or directory

Makefile:16: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 127

My python is installed in

usr/bin/python3.6m

usr/bin/python3.6

usr/bin/python2.7

Or at least that's what I find when I run:

find /usr -type f -name 'python*' -perm -a+x

Update: I ran "sudo apt-get install python" and ran "make" and had a huge list of outputs, then ran ./sage, which crashed very quickly.

Comment: What python is in your $PATH? `type -a python`

Comment: @glennjackman it is in usr/bin/python

Comment: If you do `ls -l /usr/bin/python` is it a symlink to python2 or python3?

Comment: It says python2.7

Answer (score 1):

It seems this requires python2, but not a specific version of it to execute. You need to have the `python-minimal` package installed, as it is what provides the `/usr/bin/python` symlink.

Comment: I've already had that installed